# My Get Request Works on Browser, Fails on Mobile

Tags: c#, android, angular, cordova, .net-core

I have a project which front end is angular backend is .net core web api and i am using Cordova to convert this project to APK. But i have a big problem. My GET request works well on browser (which i used 'cordova run browser' command) but when i try get request on mobile, nothing happens. I am assuming that my backend works on localhost. My browser can access local host but my Android Studio Emulator phone can't access localhost. How can i fix that? Please help me thank you!

This is my code piece where i try to get request.

```
  ngOnInit() {

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", this.onDeviceReady, false);
    this.onBrowserReady(); // TEST BROWSER
  }

  onDeviceReady() {
    alert(1)
    cordova.getAppVersion.getVersionCode(function(version) {
      alert(2)
      this.versionService.GetNewVersion().subscribe(x => {
        alert(3);
        this.object2 = new Object();
        this.object2 = x;
      });
    });


  }
```

Comment: Did you add permissions? And not sure with angular, but in android, it should be on a separate thread. Maybe reading this can help you? https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting

Comment: Yes i added permissions. All of them.